# Java safe publication

Tags: многопоточность, java

Есть класс:

```
public class A {
    public int f;
    public A() { f = 42; }
}
```

который используется двумя потоками:

```
class Thread1 {
    private A a;

    Thread1(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void run() {
        a = new A();
    }
}
```

и вторым:

```
class Thread2 {
    private A a;

    Thread1(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (a != null) {
            System.out.print(a.f);
        }
    }
}
```

Если запустить два потока, передав в них ссылку на объект *A*, то будет один из четырёх сценариев:

1) напечатает 42, если поток прочел поле из проинициализированного объекта;

2) не напечатает ничего, если объект есть null и поток это увидел;

3) напечатает 0, если первый поток начал инициализацию объекта, а второй вклинился в тот момент, когда не отработал new A() в первом потоке;

4) NullPointerException - если не повезло и при гонке на чтении сначала *a != null*, а потом спрашивается поле у *a = null*

Но если во втором потоке скопировать глобальную переменную в локальную, то NPE не будет:

```
class Thread2 {
    private A a;

    Thread1(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void run() {
        A anotherA = a;
        if (anotherA != null) {
            System.out.print(anotherA.f);
        }
    }
}
```

Почему?

У каждого потока своя копия локальных переменных - но как это влияет на публикацию?

Comment: Хм. А где у вас глобальная переменная? `Thread2` поменяет лишь свою локальную копию.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, как правильно заметил [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), у вас нет глобальной переменной. 
Во-вторых, вы не копируете переменную, а просто создаете на нее еще одну ссылку.
В-третьих, в первом потоке вы переписываете значение ссылки `a`, и теперь эты ссалка указывает на новый экземпляр объекта, который заключен лишь в этом потоке.

Ну и в-четвертых, причем здесь безопасная публикация?